# Will a PSU with Active PFC Work with Normal UPS

Tags: power-supply, ups, sine

Im getting a Seasonic SII 620 with Active PFC.The problem is that i have a pseudo sine wave ups or just a normal UPS.Will this PSU work with the back up power offered by the UPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends (but most likely yes.)

Active PFC controllers will shape the input current to whatever input voltage waveform is sensed. The current will be as non-sinusoidal as the voltage, but will be in phase with it. The closer your UPS output is to a proper sine wave, the more likely your active PFC will work just fine.

That being said, there's a strong possibility that even with a square or trapezoidal waveform, the PFC may still 'work' with some degradation (noisy operation, reduced power output, etc.).

(I use an Antec-supplied ColdWatt active PFC front-end PC PSU with an older APC UPS - which provides a squarish sine wave - and things are fine. I also design PFC converters for a living.)

EDIT: No FUD here, I don't design UPSs but often have to make my PSU "work" with a square wave UPS for one reason or another.

The performance of the power supply when presented with a square-wave input will depend on many things.

1. The active PFC controller. There are some reduced-pin-count parts that don't actually have input waveshape sensing and some firmware-driven PFC microcontrollers that expect a sine wave, that could produce output without the PFC function (input current in phase with input voltage).
2. Input undervoltage sensing is often done by peak detecting the incoming sine wave and comparing it with a fixed reference. The relationship between peak and RMS obviously differs for a sine wave and a pseudo-sine or square wave, so you can see problems like the start-up RMS voltage being higher when the input is square vs sine.
3. The square edges of the input AC waveform can cause acoustic noise to be generated in the input EMI filter magnetic components and ceramic capacitors (Y-caps). Also, the fast edges will cause higher peak currents (vs. a sine wave) as the EMI components are charged and dischared per-cycle.

Comment: Thanks,Hope it will work.My old UPS is a cheap one,i don't know anything about it.I will try to get an APC may be 700VA is good enough,even though the PSU is rated 600W the PC will draw maximum power of 480W.Hope this will be good enough

Comment: As [I have asked before](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Talk:Basic_Electrical_Generation_and_Distribution#Disputed), I want to know specific details of how exactly things fail, so I can design things to avoid those failure modes. Do you know any specific examples of anything that is "less likely to work" or has "noisy operation" or has "reduced power output" with a square, trapezoidal, or modified-sine UPS? Or is this a bunch of FUD from sine-wave UPS manufacturers? (Should I post this as an independent question?)

Comment: @techno: a 700VA UPS is hardly enough for 480W power draw. However, a PC is highly unlikely to draw 480W, so you may expect that UPS to be able to feed your PC.

Comment: Is there a PSU - UPS compatibility list? I have an old APC and want to buy an EVGA B3, but I am not sure whether they are compatible.